# Does sharedUserId needs same signing keystore for multiple apps?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-keystore

I need to share SharedPreference between my multiple apps. I found this way to share SharedPreference. But I am not sure if I strictly need to sign both APKs with same keystore file.

[Official page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid) describes little about it.

> However, if this attribute is set to the same value for two or more
>   apps, they will all share the same ID — provided that their
>   certificate sets are identical.

`provided that their certificate sets are identical` does this mean only for keystore for release?

Please confirm if I need to sign with same keys for releasing APK.

Answer (score 0):

No. it does not require the same keys for both the app.

Comment: Can you please provide a source of this information. Because it is major thing to verify before publishing apps.

Comment: Sorry, your statement seems wrong. Can anyone read other apps important secrets stored in SharedPreference just by `sharedUserId`. Which can be received just by de-compiling with any tool in android.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using sharedUserId with the same uid among your apps requires them to be signed with the same key. Note, multiple keys can be stored in the same keystore and you need to use the same private key.

Before you upload your apps to the playstore, you can verify the apps are signed by the same key using:

> apksigner verify --verbose --print-certs myapp.apk

The output of that command (replace myapp.apk with your app) needs to be the same for all apps you have sharing the same uid.

Otherwise, I actually recommend not using sharedUserId and finding a different way of sharing information between apps. Try [content providers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers) or some other IPC mechanism.